# Converting date string to another string

Tags: java, android, sql, date, datetime

How can I convert from "2014-10-13T10:41:22.863+08:00" into "2014-10-13 10:41"?

I have failed to do so:

```
String date = "2014-10-13T10:41:22.863+8:00";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
Date dateTime = null;
try {
    dateTime = dateFormat.parse(date);
} catch(ParseException e) { ... }
System.out.printf(dateTime.toString()); ...
```

Gives

> ParseException 2014-10-13T10:41:22.863+8:00

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date

Comment: It really is to use replace...thahks!

Comment: Or else, you can just split & substring all the way without converting it to `Date` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

The Z at the end is usually the timezone offset. If you you don't need it maybe you can drop it on both sides.

```
SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
try{
    Date d = df1.parse("2014-10-13T10:41:22.863+8:00");
    System.out.println("new date format " + df2.format(d));
}catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much answers this way really good, successful resolution of my problem, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to do some operation/manipulation on the `Date` before printing it in correct format, then you can just directly transform the string into `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` with this:

```
String date = "2014-10-13T10:41:22.863+8:00";

date = date.substring(0, 16);  // 2014-10-13T10:41, remove value after minutes
date = date.replace("T", " "); // 2014-10-13 10:41, replace the 'T' character

System.out.println(date);      // 2014-10-13 10:41
```

Else, if you want to parse it beforehand, then change the pattern to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm` (note the additional of string constant **`'T'`**).

```
String date = "2014-10-13T10:41:22.863+8:00";

// parse the String to Date
SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm");
Date dateTime = null;
try {
    dateTime = sourceFormat.parse(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(dateTime.toString()); // Mon Oct 13 10:41:00 SGT 2014

// print the Date in expected format
SimpleDateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
System.out.println(targetFormat.format(dateTime)); // 2014-10-13 10:41
```

The reason you got `ParseException` is because the format you use to parse (`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`) is not the same as the source (`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm ...`). Your `SimpleDateFormatter` expected whitespace instead of character 'T' after the date.

Comment: Thank you very much answers this way I thought about just wanted to see if there is a better way.